# width preserving polyhedron simplification

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I need to simplify a 3d polyhedron while controlling the maximum allowable deviation of the width after simplification.

Does anybody know of a c++ library\c++ implementation\algorithm which allows for this?

I have read about CGAL mesh simplification, and I did not see an option to control for mesh maximal width deviation.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you define the width but using [isotropic remeshing](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__meshing__grp.html) might be doing a good job here since all points in the remesh polyhedron will lie on the original surface at the end. One drawback is that the algorithm requires a edge-length to remesh the model (you cannot for example provide a number of expected edges).